# Bypassing Grails proxy settings for local repositories

Tags: grails

I'm developing a Grails 2.0.x application that of course has several external dependencies. Since I'm sitting behind a corporate firewall I've configurerd my `ProxySettings.groovy` to allow access to internet, which works as it should. 
 
Now we also need to include dependencies to some local artifacts (from other projects), which can be found in our local Maven repository. Our corporate network setup is to use the proxy only for external sites, not internal ones. So when Grails resolve my dependencies at startup it downloads all the external artifacts fine, but fails when trying to fetch our local dependencies. If I completely remove the content of my `ProxySettings.groovy`-file, then the opposite is true, Grails can't resolve the external dependencies, but does manage to download the JARs from our local Maven repository. 
I've tried to find documentation on how to exclude internal sites from using the proxy-settings in Grails, but failed miserably so far. 
 
One other alternative could perhaps be to remove (or change) the proxy settings programmtically in `BuildConfig.groovy` before the call to `mavenRepo`? 
 
Currently we are not using Maven to build our Grails projects (since we previously have had some issues with creating release builds on the build server). 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Right now I do not thing there is an easy way to get around this.

There is currently an open bug for being able to switch the Proxy-Setting programmtically

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7658

Another option would be to move the internal dependencies inside your grails project.

or you could just dump everything in BuildConfig.groovy

```
System.properties.putAll([
   "http.proxyHost": "myproxy.hostname.com",
   "http.proxyPort": "8080",
   "http.proxyUserName": "myUser",
   "http.proxyPassword": "myPass"
])
```

clear it out for the internal dependencies and then you might be good.